# How do I retrieve a specific image from an array?

Tags: android, image, kotlin

I have an app that is trying to select a specific card from a deck.
I've gotten some code together to create a file path to where the images should be stored, I think.

How do I actually reference the images in the array in can then use them in ImageViews in my app.

I have the images saved in the drawable folder, and I also created a string array of them in an attempt to maybe locate them easier.

I'm sort of just swinging wild at this point, and am in need of direction.

This is as far as I've gotten:

**String array**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Card image array -->
<string-array name="card_images">
    <!-- Clubs -->
    <item>@drawable/clubs_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_4</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_5</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_6</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_7</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_8</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_9</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_10</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_jack</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_king</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_queen</item>
    <item>@drawable/clubs_ace</item>
    <!-- Hearts -->
    <item>@drawable/hearts_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_4</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_5</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_6</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_7</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_8</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_9</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_10</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_jack</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_king</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_queen</item>
    <item>@drawable/hearts_ace</item>
    <!-- Spades -->
    <item>@drawable/spades_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_4</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_5</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_6</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_7</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_8</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_9</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_10</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_jack</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_king</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_queen</item>
    <item>@drawable/spades_ace</item>
    <!-- Diamonds -->
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_4</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_5</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_6</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_7</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_8</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_9</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_10</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_jack</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_king</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_queen</item>
    <item>@drawable/diamonds_ace</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

**GameVariables**

```
cardImageArray.forEach {
            if (!found){
                // Gets the suit of the card image that it is currently viewing.
                // Creates the suit name from the file path using substring
                val cardImageSuit = it.substring(it.indexOf("e/") + 2, it.indexOf("_"))
                val cardImageNumber = it.substring(it.indexOf("_") + 1, it.indexOf("."))

                if (cardImageSuit == suit.lowercase() && cardImageNumber == number.lowercase()) {
                    found = true
                    // Generate image path from an array element, add the suit_number to it
                    val imagePath = cardImageArray[0].substring(0, cardImageArray[0].indexOf(cardImageSuit[0]))
                    cardOut = imagePath + cardImageSuit + "_" + cardImageNumber

                }
            }
        }
```

**GameActivity**

```
gameVariables.playerHands.forEach {
            val cardImagePath = gameVariables.updateHandImages(it.firstCard, cardImageArray)

            if (cardImageArray.contains(cardImagePath)) {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain clearly what you're trying to accomplish? You have an array of Strings that weirdly look like how you would reference drawable resources in an XML file. Are these actual drawable resources that you have? What are you trying to achieve in the Kotlin code (what's the input, and what's the desired output)?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm trying to get an image at a certain location. I have 52 images in the drawables folder, and I have no problem getting the file path of one of them (let's say res/drawable/clubs_2.png). I need to know how to use that path to get the actual image to be used in an imageview

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
val initialPath = image.substring(0, image.indexOf("e/") + 2) + image + ".png"
val uri = "@drawable/" + it
val imageResource = resources.getIdentifier(uri, null, packageName)
testImageView.setImageResource(imageResource)
```